# NavigationUI.setupWithNavController get java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, controller, navigation

I am trying to implement navigation between fragments using bottom navbar but when using NavigationUI.setupWithNavController when i click on any tab i get error java.lang.NullPointerException at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected please help i dont understand what not this way.

Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testfragments, PID: 12083
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.kt:69)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupWithNavController$lambda-6(NavigationUI.kt:602)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.$r8$lambda$6wzEv9QqEZKdQFS1sQQy-bdQvgE(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onNavigationItemSelected(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationBarView.java:295)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView$1.onClick(NavigationBarMenuView.java:133)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavController navController;
private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container);
    NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_menu);
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.user, R.id.orders, R.id.products, R.id.companies, R.id.map).build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return navController.navigateUp();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_user_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_user"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/orders"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_orders_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_orders"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/products"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_products_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_products"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/companies"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_companies_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_companies"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_map"/>

</menu>
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@+id/user">

<include app:graph="@navigation/user"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/orders"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/products"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/companies"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/map"/>

</navigation>
```

Comment: try to change your fragment names. it just a naming problem. fragment name should be different than the already used names.

Comment: What was the solution?